# Elaboration of a step in the proof of Fatou's Lemma (Royden $4^{th}$ edition pg.82).

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

The lemma and a part of its proof are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**My question is:**

Why $h_{n}(x) \rightarrow h(x)$? could anyone explain this for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $h \le f$ then for any $x$ then $h(x)=f(x)$ or $h(x)<f(x)$. The convergence in the first case is clear from the definition of $h_n$, now suppose that $h(x)<f(x)$, then from the definition of $h_n$ we have that $h_n(x)=h(x)$ for all $n\ge N$ for some large enough $N\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: but in the second case $h(x) < f(x)$ not $h(x) < f_{n}(x)$ ...... for me it is not very clear the relation between $f $&$ f_{n}$ &$ h$ .... could you clarify this to me please?

Comment: note that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ then at some $N\in\Bbb N$ $f_n(x)>h(x)$ for all $n\ge N$. Just write down the $\epsilon -\delta $ definition for a convergent sequence and note that $f(x)-h(x)=c>0$ for some $c$

Comment: And are $f_{n}$'s greater than $f$ or smaller than $f$?

Comment: @Secretly there is no need to $f_n$ to approach $f$ from above or below, $f$ is just the point-wise limit of $(f_n)$, then each sequence $(f_n(x))$ doesn't have a prescribed way to approach to $f(x)$